# Android Service connection to external database

Tags: android, android-service, notificationservices

This is my first post. I'm working on a project where User keep sending data to the `Server` and a Clint receives it. Just assume the example of Facebook where friend post things and we get `Notification`. I'm currently doing the same trying to make a `NotificationService` which will be connected to DB and keep track of user's new data and Clint get the notification.

I need help to find the logic of this, how to keep connected to server and receive the data, Where data receiving function keep running continuously.

Any link of this and demo is just appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here you can only ask question related to programming - questions asking for book, tutorial recommendation are off-topic and broad questions generally end-up being closed!

Comment: @Hatef, thanks for encounter, but I'm stuck with an idea how to implement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well you should avoid making a permanent connection. but you can use Firebase Cloud message. you can find some good resources on firebase.google.com